# Why is my dict being overwritten in this loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dict, `coords_dict`, in a strange format. Which is currently being used to store a set of Cartesian coordinate points (x,y,z). The structure of the dict (which is unfortunately out of my control) is as follows.

The keys of the dict are a series of z values of a plane, and each entry consists of a single element list, which itself is a list of lists containing the coordinate points. For example, two elements in the dict can be specified as

```
coords_dict['3.5']=[[[1.62,2.22,3.50],[4.54,5.24,3.50]]]
coords_dict['5.0']=[[[0.33,6.74,5.00],[2.54,12.64,5.00]]]
```

So, I now want to apply some translational shift to all coordinate points in this dict by some shift vector `[-1,-1,-1]`, i.e. I want all x, y, and z coordinates to be 1 less than they were before (rounded to 2 decimal places). And I want to assign the result of this translation to a new dictionary, `coords_dict_translated`, while also updating the dict keys to match the z locations of all points

My attempt at a solution is below

```
import numpy as np
shift_vector=[-1,-1,-1]
coords_dict_translated={}
for key,plane in coords_dict.items(): #iterate over dictionary, k are keys representing each plane
    key=str(float(key)+shift_vector[2]) #the new key should match the z location
    #print(key)
    for point_index in range(0,len(plane[0])): #loop over points in this plane
        plane[0][point_index]=list(np.around(np.array(plane[0][point_index])
                                   +np.array(shift_vector),decimals=2)) #add shift vector to all points    
    coords_dict_translated[key]=plane
```

However, I notice that if I do this that that the original values of `coords_dict` are also changing. I want `coords_dict` to stay the same but return a completely new and entirely separate dict. I am not quite sure where the issue lies, I have tried using `for key,plane in list(coords_dict.items()):` as well but this did not work. Why does this loop change the values of the original dictionary?

Comment: Without looking in detail at your issue, I'm going to say you probably have a list that is being referenced from two different variables; you need to make sure you are making a (deep) copy of lists you want to update independently. [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Comment: Thanks, using copy.deepcopy in the loop worked. Original I was using copy by itself but that wasn't working. What is the different between copy and deepcopy?

Comment: deepcopy iteratively copies lists in lists - I'll write an answer & add this if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are iterating over the dictionary in the for loop you are referencing the elements in your list/array:

```
for key,plane in coords_dict.items(): #iterate over dictionary, k are keys representing each plane
```

If you don't want to change the items, you should just make a copy of the variable you are using instead of setting `plane` directly:

```
import copy
key=str(float(key)+shift_vector[2]) #the new key should match the z location
    #print(key)
    c = copy.deepcopy(plane)
    for point_index in range(0,len(plane[0])): #loop over points in this plane
        c[0][point_index]=list(np.around(np.array(plane[0][point_index])
                                   +np.array(shift_vector),decimals=2)) #add shift vector to all points    
    coords_dict_translated[key] = c
```

Comment: I have tried this but for some reason the original coords_dict is still not staying static, its values change. I have even tried to cast the original coords_dict to a copy with copy=coords_dict.copy() before looping and even copy keeps changing values. I can't quite figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue here is that you have a list that is being referenced from two different variables. This can happen even using `.copy()` when you have nested structure (as you do here).

If this is the problem, you can probably overcome it by using need to make sure you are making a (deep) copy of lists you want to update independently. [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) will iteratively make copies of lists within lists etc. to avoid double references to lower-level lists.

(comment made into answer).